# ¿Como implementar table editor de Material Design for Boostrap (MDB)?

Tags: javascript, html5, mdb

Busque en Internet la forma de usar una tabla que sea editable por el lado del cliente, encontré esto https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/table-editor/, la primera me interesa y *no se que código Javascript se usa para la selección, ingreso, edición, eliminación de fila en HTML*.

**Trate con dos opciones:**

> 1. Copiar el código fuente de MDB

Le quite el HTML que no usare y deje enlaces, CSS y script.

Esta en un enlace externo por que supera los 10.000 caracteres permitidos en stackoverflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/nbayrqs1/

http://jsfiddle.net/oLuweav3/

> 2. Usar el código que muestra MDB

Recomiendo descargar MDB para su mejor uso

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/getting-started/download/

```js
$('#dtBasicExample').mdbEditor({
  headerLength: 6,
  evenTextColor: '#000',
  oddTextColor: '#000',
  bgEvenColor: '',
  bgOddColor: '',
  thText: '',
  thBg: '',
  modalEditor: true,
  bubbleEditor: true,
  contentEditor: true,
  rowEditor: true
});
$('#dtBasicExample').mdbEditor({
  mdbEditor: true
});
$('.dtBasicExample').addClass('bs-select');
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-editor">

  <div class="block my-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p class="h5 text-primary createShowP">0 row selected</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center modalWrapper">
    <div class="modal fade addNewInputs" id="modalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAdd"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold text-primary ml-5">Add new form</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close text-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body mx-3">
            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputName">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="inputPosition" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputPosition">Position</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="inputOfficeInput" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputOfficeInput">Office</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="inputAge" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputAge">Age</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="date" id="inputDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputDate"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="inputSalary" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="inputSalary">Salary</label>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center buttonAddFormWrapper">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block buttonAdd" data-dismiss="modal">Add form
              <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdd">Add<i
          class="fas fa-plus-square ml-1"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade modalEditClass" id="modalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold text-secondary ml-5">Edit form</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close text-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body mx-3">
            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formNameEdit" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formNameEdit">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formPositionEdit" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formPositionEdit">Position</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formOfficeEdit" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formOfficeEdit">Office</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formAgeEdit" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formAgeEdit">Age</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formDateEdit" class="form-control datepicker">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formDateEdit">Date</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <input type="text" id="formSalaryEdit" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="formSalaryEdit">Salary</label>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center editInsideWrapper">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block editInside" data-dismiss="modal">Edit
              form
              <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center buttonEditWrapper">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm buttonEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit"
        disabled>Edit<i class="fas fa-pencil-square-o ml-1"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDelete"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold ml-5 text-danger">Delete</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close text-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body mx-3">
            <p class="text-center h4">Are you sure to delete selected row?</p>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center deleteButtonsWrapper">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnYesClass" id="btnYes" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNoClass" id="btnNo" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-rounded buttonDelete" data-toggle="modal" disabled data-target="#modalDelete"
        disabled>Delete<i class="fas fa-times ml-1"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">Name

        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Position

        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Office

        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Age

        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Start date

        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Salary

        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Position
        </th>
        <th>Office
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
        <th>Start date
        </th>
        <th>Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: y cual es tu duda?

Comment: Hola @JuanPerez, yo no dudo, pregunto como implementar table editor de MDB, para que funcione los códigos javascript al momento de: selección, ingreso, edición, eliminación de fila